# How to convert Message to Float in Gnuradio

Tags: c++, gnuradio

I have a cpp block that asynchronously produces a message containing a float value. How can I plot or show this value using available Qt GUI blocks. As QT Gui Number Sink and Time Sink require input of type float whereas my block gives output of message type.

The code I am using to send message is as follows:

```
float my_float_value = 0.982069;

message_port_pub(pmt::mp("out"), pmt::cons(pmt::PMT_NIL, pmt::from_float(my_float_value)));
```

When I connect Message Debug block, I get following output in console

> ```
> ******* MESSAGE DEBUG PRINT ********
> (() . 0.982609)
> ************************************
> ```

How can I plot this using QT Gui Number Sink or Time Sink ?

Comment: QT GUI Time sink seems to have an option of "Float message" as input type. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the float value using Function probe block and use QT GUI Label to show the value in your QT GUI Time Sink.